# How to do REST-ful updates?

Tags: rest

If I have an object, say `Employee`, and I want to offer 2 different ways of updating it -- update performance rating, or update contact info.

What is the REST-ful way of structuring the API?  I assume the right method is POST.

My concern is that it seems inelegant for a user to first GET both parts of the object (performance rating and contact info), update just one part, and POST the entire updated object.

My other concern is that it seems inelegant to sent an object with only certain fields filled in because the schema for the object requires all fields to be complete, and the omission of fields is only to support the POST.  I. e. it would need separate schemas just to support the operations or doing without schemas -- neither of seems right.

Similarly, using flags for what fields to update also requires a different schema just for the operation.

Providing separate methods does not fit in any obvious way into the noun-verb paradigm.

HOW are REST APIs supposed to look when they are required to handle such cases? Does there need to be a many-to-one mapping between REST nouns and application entities?  If so, do we restrict PUT for the view entities which would represent subsets of application entities?

I am not looking for a hack or an inelegant way. I am looking for what the REST philosophy would consider the right solution.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: a different answer provides a way to update individual fields by a POST to /employee/123/performance_rating but that does not apply to contact info which comprises multiple fields: {street, city, phone, etc.} which you want to update in a single shot

Comment: WRT. PUT vs POST:

Use PUT to update a resource whose full URI is already known.

Use POST to create a new resource, if the new resource's URI is not known a priori, because, e.g. its URI contains a server generated id.

Comment: You would pass the street/city/phone in as request parameters (or optionally url parameters).  Then, on server side, use employee/123 to retrieve object from db; and then set street/city/phone using the values passed in, and then resave the object w/the new info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fights against your concerns, but seeing how Rating and Info are also resources I would make the API like this (thanks taylonr for the template :)

```
url/employees/{id}/[rating|info]
```

This way you can GET a representation of all the employees, an employee with a certain id, performance rating of an employee with a certain id and the contact info of an employee with a certain id.

Creating a new employee with initialized contact info and performance rating

```
POST url/employees { "id": "johnsmith", "rating": 4, "info": ["address": "street 1 a 1" , "email": "johns.old@mail.com"] }
```

Updating the 2 would work with different POSTs

```
PUT url/employees/johnsmith/rating  { "rating": 5 }
PUT url/employees/johnsmith/info { "email": "john.smith@company.com" }
```

Comment: I suggest reverse the PUT and POST here; POST to url/employees, to have server create url/employess/johnsmith, or else PUT to url/employees/johnsmith if you already know that that's the URI for that resource.  And PUT to url/employees/johnsmith/rating and /info, since you know the complete URI for those resources.

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite good. Let me read the rest (sorry) of the answers.

Comment: @Topi, thanks very much. I believe you have the right answer so far and I will accept it after a sufficient amount of time has passed (I keep my acceptance % at 100 so I'll be sure not to forget :)

Comment: @smendola -- thank you for adding valuable information. i'll go find some of your answers i can upvote ;-)

Comment: Actually, I wrote my bachelors on the subject!  :) Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this depends on how this is supposed to be used.

If you're just going to do something like simply have the client pass in ALL information needed to update the ENTIRE Employee object, then you only need to expose one endpoint, and you can just do...

```
domain/employee/{employee_id}
```

Like @taylonr explained.  This is more likely the scenario for an API you're exposing to 3rd parties.  The reason you would make a method like this is because it allows third parties to then build their own functionality to update an entire resource; and then pass that to you.  In other words, having the entire resource available is a good catch all; but probably not the best if you're using it for your own web application.

But, if this is the backend of a web application, and you're going to do something related; but doesn't require knowing all information to perform the intended action, then you could follow this kind of paradigm:

```
domain/employee/{employee_id}/action
```

So, for example, when I upvoted your post, the post that Stackoverflow is using under the hood was....

```
                         noun    noun verb verb
                           |       |     |  | 
                           |       |     |  |
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8478829/vote/2
```

The reason this is done this way is because all you need is the URL and session information (your authenticated object on the server side) and you can do everything you need.

You said that

> My other concern is that it seems inelegant to sent an object with only certain fields filled in because the schema for the object requires all fields to be complete, and the omission of fields is only to support the POST. I. e. it would need separate schemas just to support the operations or doing without schemas -- neither of seems right.

but I don't think this is a valid concern.  Instead of relying the client to pass all information for the object it would like to update, you just use the "noun" part - `posts/8478829` = and resolve the resource server side.

Comment: I'm not sure how RESTful it is, to use a verb in an URL rather than the HTTP request method

Comment: No one said that the verb being used in the url has to be an http verb.  Think of it from a more object oriented approach, ex Vote extends HttpPost.  Even though there is a strict list of HTTP verbs; I don't think it means that those are the only verbs which can be used to resolve the intended action on the specified resource (I'm pretty sure that list is just for webservers which explicitly claim to implement http).  Given, I don't have a quote handy from the spec to back me up but I would be EXTREMELY surprised if the spec said "you can only use the http verbs in your URL structure".

Comment: @Dave, (re Topi's comment) I think you are on the right track but you are merely calling the noun the verb -- vote is both a noun and a verb, and in stackoverflow's case I am sure the intent is to update your vote to the value 2. stackoverflow's API is slightly and understandably inelegant in that it should be: /posts/8478829/votingusersid/vote/2 but that's understandable since the votingusersid is implicit.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the neat write up, esp. formatting. I do think @Topi's post better addresses my concerns in coming up with sub-resources within the URL [rating/contact]. But you did take a lot of trouble to write it up so I'm upvoting regardless :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
PUT myuri/Employee/{id}
```

And the body of the request has the Employee object.  That way the consumer updates whatever they want and give's it back to you.  Since the user would already have the ID, you could do a PUT.

That's how we typically do it on APIs I've worked on.

The advantage of giving back the entire object is because the API needs to know if the version the user has is the most up-to-date (e.g. with an ETag).  If the consumer tries to update something that is out of date, then it should fail.

Comment: Thanks but that requires either a patching scheme or requires the consumer to GET more information than they need just so they can post it back. i was looking for the right/pure/elegant solution.

Comment: Quoting Fielding:

_The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction._

As I interpret this, therefore, your need to update a sub-record of an employee record is not what REST is optimized for; and therefore, unfortunately, you have to choose between optimization and pure RESTfulnes.

Comment: How do you know 1. That the user SHOULD be updating the data and 2. That the data they're updating to is allowed?  E.g. 2 people update contact information, the first one updates an old version.  That should be blocked, because the resource has changed.  The only way to handle that is to have the user send in the resource version (etag) and the only way for them to have that is to do a get.

Comment: upvoting for the discussion of how to ensure most up-to-date. (this does not apply to my use case however because performance rating and contact info are assumed to be totally independent) nevertheless your discussion does have a point in other situations.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, contact info might not be so independent.  You and I consume the API.  We've both done a GET to show contact info on a website.  Each of our users updates the contact info, only my guy doesn't actually change anything.  Your guy changes city & state and PUT's before my guy can.  When I PUT mine back, mine will update w/o incident, reverting all the changes back to the old data.  This is a real situation that can happen. Remember, you're controlling the API not the conditions the consumer sends you data.  You need to have a way to prevent bad data.

Answer (score 2):

PUT to the same URI you GET from.

A REST API can have a one-to-one mapping between resources and things. Or a many-to-one mapping between resources and things. Just what "things" is, is up to you; it can be what you consider an application entity, but it doesn't have to if it makes sense for it to e.g. represent only part of such an entity.

If I'm user of your API, I really don't care what you do or don't consider an entity in your implementation, I care about what you consider a resource in your web service.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the relatively new [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) HTTP verb, and a custom schema for your patch/diff format. This avoid polluting the semantics of PUT/POST and more closely aligns with what your need is, which is to update a subset of the attributes of the resource.

Otherwise, I would go with Topi Ojala's approach (swapping PUT/POST as someone already commented)

Comment: thanks for adding that information, but yes, i think topi's approach is preferable versus a patching scheme because when the use cases are few and known in advance (2 use cases: rating and contact). patching would probably be preferable if there are quite a few cases or if the cases are not known in advance. (upvoting for adding information)